# Trying to insert data where not exists throwing: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, not-exists

I'm getting data from one table and trying to insert it into another, if the data does not already exist, this works when the "not exists" only returns 1 row but if it returns more than one it fails.

Here is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO datatables.SoftwareProjects_Tasks (Description, Project_ID, 
Task_Status) 

SELECT * FROM (SELECT Task FROM datatables.DefaultTask Where Department_Id =
5) as a, (SELECT sp.id FROM datatables.SoftwareProjects AS sp
INNER JOIN S4Admin.Project AS p ON sp.s4_project_id = p.Project_Code
WHERE p.Project_Code = 2294) as b, (SELECT 3) as c

WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT Description, Project_ID FROM SoftwareProjects_Tasks WHERE Description 
= (SELECT Task FROM datatables.DefaultTask Where Department_Id = 5) AND 
Project_ID = (SELECT sp.id FROM datatables.SoftwareProjects AS sp
INNER JOIN S4Admin.Project AS p ON sp.s4_project_id = p.Project_Code
WHERE p.Project_Code = 2294)  
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trouble is here

```
WHERE Description = (SELECT Task FROM datatables.DefaultTask Where Department_Id = 5)
      AND Project_ID = (SELECT sp.id FROM datatables.SoftwareProjects AS sp INNER JOIN S4Admin.Project AS p ON sp.s4_project_id = p.Project_Code WHERE p.Project_Code = 2294)
```

I don't think that your query is correct. And I recommend to try to use another way

```
--INSERT INTO datatables.SoftwareProjects_Tasks (Description, Project_ID, Task_Status)
SELECT a.Task,a.Project_ID,3 AS Task_Status
FROM
  (
    SELECT t.Task,p.Project_ID
    FROM datatables.DefaultTask AS t,
      (
        SELECT sp.id AS Project_ID
        FROM datatables.SoftwareProjects AS sp
        JOIN S4Admin.Project AS p ON sp.s4_project_id = p.Project_Code
        WHERE p.Project_Code=2294
      ) AS p
    WHERE t.Department_Id=5
  ) a
LEFT JOIN SoftwareProjects_Tasks b ON b.Description=a.Task AND b.Project_ID=a.Project_ID
WHERE b.Project_ID IS NULL
```

And you can try to use the `MINUS` operator if your version of MySQL supported it

```
--INSERT INTO datatables.SoftwareProjects_Tasks (Description, Project_ID, Task_Status)
SELECT Task,Project_ID,3
FROM
  (
    SELECT t.Task,p.Project_ID
    FROM datatables.DefaultTask AS t,
      (
        SELECT sp.id AS Project_ID
        FROM datatables.SoftwareProjects AS sp
        JOIN S4Admin.Project AS p ON sp.s4_project_id = p.Project_Code
        WHERE p.Project_Code=2294
      ) AS p
    WHERE t.Department_Id=5

    MINUS

    SELECT Description,Project_ID
    FROM SoftwareProjects_Tasks
  ) q
```

See the following article about `MINUS` in MySQL - http://gokhanatil.com/2010/10/minus-and-intersect-in-mysql.html

And one more variant with `NOT EXISTS`

```
--INSERT INTO datatables.SoftwareProjects_Tasks (Description, Project_ID, Task_Status)
SELECT t.Task,p.Project_ID,3 AS Task_Status
FROM datatables.DefaultTask AS t,
  (
    SELECT sp.id AS Project_ID
    FROM datatables.SoftwareProjects AS sp
    JOIN S4Admin.Project AS p ON sp.s4_project_id = p.Project_Code
    WHERE p.Project_Code=2294
  ) AS p
WHERE t.Department_Id=5
  AND NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM SoftwareProjects_Tasks b
      WHERE b.Description=t.Task AND b.Project_ID=p.Project_ID
    )
```

Hope I understood you correctly.

And maybe you need to add `DISTINCT` for the subquery with `Project_ID`

```
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT sp.id AS Project_ID
    FROM datatables.SoftwareProjects AS sp
    JOIN S4Admin.Project AS p ON sp.s4_project_id = p.Project_Code
    WHERE p.Project_Code=2294
  ) AS p
```

Comment: Ah man, you are a legend. Your first suggestion works like a charm! Going to study it for a while to improve my way of doing things. Thanks so much!